# unexpected behaviour in shell command substitution

Tags: shell

Given the shell script `test.sh`

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

and the invocation `sh test.sh $(echo '"hello " "hi and bye"')`

I would expect the output

```
hello
hi and bye
```

but instead get:

```
"hello
"
"hi
and
bye"
```

If I change to `sh test.sh $(echo "hello " "hi and bye")`

then I get

```
hello
hi
and
bye
```

Neither of these behaviours are desired, how can I get the desired behaviour?

What I want to understand is why `sh test.sh $(echo "hello " "hi and bye")` and `sh test.sh "hello " "hi and bye"` are not equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your command substitution will generate a string.

In the case of

```
$(echo '"hello " "hi and bye"')
```

this string will be `"hello " "hi and bye"`.

The string is then undergoing word splitting (and filename globbing, but it doesn't affect this example).  The word splitting happen on every character that is the same as one of the characters in `$IFS` (by default, spaces, tabs and newlines).

The words generated by the default value of `IFS` would be `"hello`, `"`, `"hi`, `and`, and `bye"`.

These are then given as separate arguments to your script.

In your second command, the command substitution is

```
$(echo "hello " "hi and bye")
```

This generates the string `hello  hi and bye` and the word splitting would result in the four words `hello`, `hi`, `and`, and `bye`.

In your last example, you use the *two* arguments `hello` and `hi and bye` directly with your script.  These *won't* undergo word splitting because they are quoted.

Comment: Thanks. Is the short answer to this then that you cannot (reliably) use command substitution to generate arguments to another command?

Comment: @user1207217 Correct, especially if the arguments contain characters from `$IFS` or filename globbing characters.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks, although thats a huge pain ....

Comment: @user1207217 You may want to ask a separate question about what it actually is that you are intending or trying to do.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495769/how-can-i-generate-arguments-to-another-command-via-command-substitution

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**:  the result of `echo` is a victim of word splitting on `$()` result, and `sh test.sh "hello " "hi and bye"`  uses a different rule.

Let's take a peak as what's actually happening, when you add `set -x` for debugging:

```
> set -x
> ./main.sh $(echo '"hello " "hi and bye"')
++ echo '"hello " "hi and bye"'
+ ./main.sh '"hello' '"' '"hi' and 'bye"'
"hello
"
"hi
and
bye"
```

`echo` receives `"hello " "hi and bye"` as a single argument (yep, including all spaces and single quote) due to single-quotes in the command itself. But command substitution turns that into `"hello " "hi and bye"`. To quote [bash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed **on the results**.

However, in your case, unquoted command substitution allows exactly for word splitting to occur based on blank character (which is one of the 3 characters set in the `$IFS` variable, which is what is used for word splitting). Thus, if you break the resulting string at each space, what do you have?

1. `"hello`, then space, after which we have next token
2. `"` - that one character by itself, isolated by spaces from both sides.
3. `"hi`, again with space on left and right
4. `and`
5. `bye"`

all in all, you get 5 tokens broken at whitespaces. It's important to realize that word splitting, in this case, occurs exactly a result of command substitution. Later, all of these are treated as individual tokens that have been already parsed. As you see in `set -x` output,  the shell script is called with exactly those tokens.

As for why `sh test.sh "hello " "hi and bye"` behaves differently, that's because the different rule applies. Your command-line is parsed after you enter it, and quoted strings are treated as a single unit, i.e. `hello` and `hi and bye`

Answer (score 2):

You could change `IFS` to something other than space (since you want to protect the space in `hi and bye`), and use that something to separate the two strings:

```
$ IFS=:
$ sh test.sh $(echo "hello ":"hi and bye")
hello 
hi and bye
```

The order of operations (those relevant in this example, anyway) is somewhat like this:

1. substitutions
2. word splitting
3. quote removal

Note that quotes created as a result of substitutions aren't special in word splitting or quote removal, so a quote in the output of (1) passes through (2) and (3) like any other character. So:

1. In `echo "hello " "hi and bye"`, the shell removes these quotes, so `echo` gets `hello` and `hi and bye`, so outputs `hello  hi and bye`, joining the strings with a space.
2. In `echo '"hello " "hi and bye"'`, the shell removes the outer `'`, the echo gets `"hello " "hi and bye"` and outputs that.
3. In `sh test.sh $(echo '"hello " "hi and bye"')`, the command substitution is replaced with `"hello " "hi and bye"`, but *these* quotes are a result of a substitution, and so aren't involved in word splitting or quote removal.

   So the shell splits those into `"hello`, `"`, `"hi`, `and`, `bye"`, hence the output you get.
4. In `sh test.sh $(echo "hello " "hi and bye")`, the command substitution is replaced with `hello  hi and bye`, which gets split into `hello`, `hi` and `bye`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what I am not understanding is why the usual shell substitution is not occurring, i.e. why is the behaviour not the same as if I do `sh test.sh "hello " "hi and bye"`?

Comment: @user1207217 does the edit help?

Comment: In `$(echo "hello ":"hi and bye")`, you might as well write `$(echo "hello :hi and bye")`. The colon works the same quoted or not.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sh test.sh "hello " "hi and bye"
```

?

Comment: I'm aware I can do this, the shell script is a MWE of an unexpected behaviour -- I'm trying to use a command substitution to generate a long list of args (some of which contain spaces) but it doesn't work correctly because even with quoting in the command output the above is occurring, i.e. the shell is not doing its usual parsing and treating everything inside a single or double quote pair as a single arg