# How can I generate arguments to another command via command substitution

Tags: shell, arguments, command-substitution

Following on from:
[unexpected behaviour in shell command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495755/unexpected-behaviour-in-shell-command-substitution)

I have a command which can take a huge list of arguments, some of which can legitimately contain spaces (and probably other things)

I wrote a script which can generate those arguments for me, with quotes,  but I must copy and paste the output e.g.

```
./somecommand
<output on stdout with quoting>
./othercommand some_args <output from above>
```

I tried to streamline this by simply doing

```
./othercommand $(./somecommand)
```

and ran into the unexpected behaviour mentioned in question above. The question is -- can command substitution be reliably used to generate the arguments to `othercommand` given that some arguments require quoting and this cannot be changed?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "reliably". If you want next command take the output exactly as it appears on screen and apply shell rules to it, then  maybe `eval` could be used, but it's generally not recommended. `xargs` is something to consider as well

Comment: I'd like (expect) the output from `somecommand` to undergo regular shell parsing

Comment: As I said in my answer, use some other character for field splitting (like `:`)... assuming that character will reliably *not* be in the output.

Comment: But that's not really right because it doesn't obey quoting rules, which is what this is about

Comment: Could you post a real-world example? I mean, the actual output of the first command and how you want it to interact with the second command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I wrote a script which can generate those arguments for me, with quotes

If the output is properly quoted for the shell, **and you trust the output**, then you could run `eval` on it.

Assuming you have a shell that supports arrays, it would be best to use one to store the arguments you get.

If `./gen_args.sh` produces output like `'foo bar' '*' asdf`, then we could run `eval "args=( $(./gen_args.sh) )"` to populate an array called `args` with the results. That would be the three elements `foo bar`, `*`, `asdf`.

We can use `"${args[@]}"` as usual to expand the array elements individually:

```
$ eval "args=( $(./gen_args.sh) )"
$ for var in "${args[@]}"; do printf ":%s:\n" "$var"; done
:foo bar:
:*:
:asdf:
```

(Note the quotes. `"${array[@]}"` expands to all elements as distinct arguments unmodified. Without quotes the array elements are subject to word splitting. See e.g. the [Arrays page on BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).)

**However**, `eval` will happily run any shell substitutions, so `$HOME` in the output would expand to your home directory, and a command substitution would actually run a command in the shell running `eval`. An output of `"$(date >&2)"` would create a single empty array element and print the current date on stdout. This is a concern if `gen_args.sh` gets the data from some untrusted source, like another host over the network, file names created by other users. **The output could include arbitrary commands.** (If `get_args.sh` itself was malicious, it wouldn't need to output anything, it could just run the malicious commands directly.)

---

An alternative to shell quoting, which is hard to parse without eval, would be to use some other character as separator in the output of your script. You'd need to pick one that is not needed in the actual arguments.

Let's choose `#`, and have the script output `foo bar#*#asdf`. Now we can use *unquoted* command expansion to split the output of the command to the arguments.

```
$ IFS='#'                          # split on '#' signs
$ set -f                           # disable globbing
$ args=( $( ./gen_args3.sh ) )     # assign the values to the array
$ for var in "${args[@]}"; do printf ":%s:\n" "$var"; done
:foo bar:
:*:
:asdf:
```

You'll need to set `IFS` back later if you depend on word splitting elsewhere in the script (`unset IFS` should work to make it the default), and also use `set +f` if you want to use globbing later.

If you're not using Bash or some other shell that has arrays, you could use the positional parameters for that. Replace `args=( $(...) )` with `set -- $(./gen_args.sh)` and use `"$@"` instead of `"${args[@]}"` then. (Here, too, you need quotes around `"$@"`, otherwise the positional parameters are subject to word splitting.)

Comment: Best of both worlds!

Comment: Would you add a remark showing the importance of quoting `${args[@]}` -- this didn't work for me otherwise

Comment: @user1207217, yes, you're right. It's the same thing with arrays and `"${array[@]}"` as with `"$@"`. Both need to be quoted, or otherwise word splitting breaks the array elements to parts.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that once your `somecommand` script outputs the options for `othercommand`, the options are really just text and at the mercy of the shell's standard parsing (affected by whatever `$IFS` happens to be and what shell options are in effect, which you in the general case would *not* be in control over).

Instead of using `somecommand` to *output* the options, it would be easier, safer, and more robust to use it to *call* `othercommand`.  The `somecommand` script would then be a *wrapper script* around `othercommand` instead of some sort of helper script that you would have to remember to call in some special way as part of the command line of `otherscript`.  Wrapper scripts are a very common way of providing a tool that just calls some other similar tool with another set of options (just check with `file` what commands in `/usr/bin` are actually shell script wrappers).

In `bash`, `ksh` or `zsh`, you could easily a wrapper script that uses an array to hold the individual options for `othercommand` like so:

```
options=( "hi there" "nice weather" "here's a star" "*" )
options+=( "bonus bumblebee!" )  # add additional option
```

Then call `othercommand` (still within the wrapper script):

```
othercommand "${options[@]}"
```

The expansion of `"${options[@]}"` would ensure that each element of the `options` array is individually quoted and presented to `othercommand` as separate arguments.

The user of the wrapper would be oblivious to the fact that it's actually calling `othercommand`, something that would *not* be true if the script instead just generated the command line options for `othercommand` as output.

In `/bin/sh`, use `$@` to hold the options:

```
set -- "hi there" "nice weather" "here's a star" "*"
set -- "$@" "bonus bumblebee!"  # add additional option

othercommand "$@"
```

(`set` is the command used for setting the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc.  These are what makes up the array `$@` in a standard POSIX shell.  The initial `--` is to signal to `set` that there are no options given, only arguments.  The `--` is *really* only needed if the first value happens to be something starting with `-`).

Note that it's the double quotes around `$@` and `${options[@]}` that ensures that the elements are not individually word-splitted (and filename globbed).

Comment: could you explain `set --` ?

Comment: @user1207217 Added explanation to answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the `somecommand` output is in reliably good shell syntax, you can use `eval`:

```
$ eval sh test.sh $(echo '"hello " "hi and bye"')
hello 
hi and bye
```

But you have to be sure that the output has valid quoting and such, otherwise you might end up running commands outside the script as well:

```
$ cat test.sh 
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "|$var|"
done
$ ls
bar  baz  test.sh
$ eval sh test.sh $(echo '"hello " "hi and bye"; echo rm *')
|hello |
|hi and bye|
rm bar baz test.sh
```

Note that `echo rm bar baz test.sh` wasn't passed to the script (because of the `;`) and was run as a separate command. I added the `|` around `$var` to highlight this.

---

Generally, unless you can completely trust the output of `somecommand`, it's not possible to reliably use its output to build a command string.